# android how to dynamically bind checkboxes with custom listview

Tags: android

I create `checkboxes` dynamically & i want to bind that `checkboxes` to `listview`.

How can I do that?

Here i give my code--

```
public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity{
    CheckBox[] chk;
    ListView lv1;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listTasks);
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
```

The database section:

```
         db = new DBAdapter(HomeActivity.this);
            db.open();//int[] id=new int[]{Integer.parseInt(DBAdapter.ID)};
    Cursor cr=db.getUncompletedTask();//my database function to retrieve values to create checkboxes
            if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String[] str=new String[2];
                    str[0]=cr.getString(0);
                    str[1]=cr.getString(1);
                    al.add(str);
                } while (cr.moveToNext());
            }
            startManagingCursor(cr);
            String[] tasks = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_TODO };
```

> Creation of checkbox:

```
    int[] idchk=new int[al.size()];//here i am creating checkbox dynamicaly
    if (al.size() != 0) {
        chk = new CheckBox[al.size()];
        System.out.println(al.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            String[] s = (String[]) al.get(i);
            System.out.println("ID: "+s[0]);
            Task_Id = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
            Task_Nm = s[1];
            chk[i] = new CheckBox(HomeActivity.this);
            System.out.println(i +"task id"+Task_Id +"parseint"+Integer.parseInt(s[0]+chk[i].getText().toString()));
            chk[i].setId(Task_Id);
            idchk[i]=Task_Id;
            chk[i].setText(Task_Nm);
            //lv1.addView(chk[i]);         
            //setContentView(lv1); 
        }}}
```

Here what can i write here so that this dynamically created `checkboxes` will be bind to `listview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use the default listview of android with checkbox.
By using :

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, COUNTRIES));
```

where COUNTRIES is static final string array that contains the item to show..

Comment: Its working but i want to bind checkboxes dynamically. that means i create checkboxes dynamically at run time. so how can i bind that checkboxes to a listview.plz give me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use customized ListView whose rows contains CheckBox. Create your own adapter extending  ArrayAdapter and it's overridden method getView create your checkboxes.